# Android NDK - does it support straight ARM code or just Thumb

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have been asked to evaluate the Android platform for our product and I am looking at various options, I am only just scratching the surface just now and the one thing that is bothering me is that I cannot see how to compile code as straight ARM code (no Thumb), I know that Thumb runs slower and we will need the performance in key sections of our code.

I *think* it should just be setting the `-march` flag in the `LOCAL_CFLAGS` of the `Android.mk` file, but I cannot get that to work...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Specifying the following flag for a module in `Android.mk` will compile straight ARM code.

```
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
```

Enabling optimization may also help:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3
```

Answer (score 17):

You can build in ARM, Thumb, or a mix of the two.

In the makefile, in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`, where you would list `MyFile.c`, specify `MyFile.c.arm` (do not rename the file on disk, just do it in the list of source files).  This convention is used throughout Android for code that is performance-critical (or just needs to be ARM for some reason).

The usual notes apply, of course: Thumb code tends to require more instructions to accomplish something, but each instruction is half the size, so the code is usually a bit slower but also a fair bit smaller.  In some situations the smaller size allows a better fit with the (tiny) caches in the ARM CPUs, and could actually be faster.