# Android NDK: fully compile in arm mode

Tags: android-ndk, arm

How to compile native code in arm mode?
After setting LOCAL_ARM_MODE to "arm",recompiling(including STLport) and starting app, I got SIGBUS exception in /system/lib/libstdc++.so.
So I can assume that that libstdc++.so complide in thumb mode.
How to compile app fully in arm mode?Or recompile libstdc++ in arm mode and link it statically.

Comment: And such code in native code initialization
`unsigned int res;
 __asm__ __volatile__
 ( " mrs r3,cpsr \n"
  "  mov %[result],r3 \n"
 : [result]"=r"(res)
 :
 :"r3");
 if( res & 0x00000010) 
  LOGD("Thumb mode is ON!!!");
        else 
         LOGD("We are in ARM MODE !!!");`

return "Thumb mode is ON!!!".
How to start app in arm mode?

Comment: For those interested in compiling to ARM mode: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6246593/755804